# different versions of git between developers

Tags: git, compatibility, versions

if I have installed version of GIT 1.9.4 and the repository on server is using 1.8.2 would there be a problem? Are there any issues with working using different versions of GIT? Does every person in a team should have the same version or does it not matter?

Could find any info on that in docs, I'd be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.9.4 and 1.8.2 are pretty close, but there *may* have a few problems between different git versions, mainly varying behaviors.

If you want to know what have changed, you can check git repository (https://github.com/git/git).
Clone it locally, and search for "compatibility" in the `Documentation/RelNotes` directory (you can target 1.8 and 1.9 versions):

```
git clone git@github.com:git/git.git
grep "compatibility" Documentation/RelNotes/1.[89]* -n
```

> Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.0.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.1.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes (this release)
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt:25:Backward compatibility notes (for Git 2.0)
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes (for Git 2.0)
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes (for Git 2.0)
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes (for Git 2.0)
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.0.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes
>   Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.0.txt:30:Backward compatibility notes (for Git 2.0.0)

You're only concerned by 1.8.3+ releases, and you can see most of compatibility issues concern Git 2.0. The only one line that is interesting is this one:

> Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.0.txt:4:Backward compatibility notes

It you take a look to `1.9.0.txt`, you'll see:

- `git submodules foreach $cmd $args` behavior has been enhanced
- loose-object format has been dropped
- `git fetch --tags` behavior has changed
- `git push $there $what` has been enhanced
- `repo-config`, `tar-tree`, `lost-found`, and `peek-remote` have been dropped

Nothing alarming but `git fetch --tags` changes, you shouldn't have any compatibility problem. Anyway, read carefully the full text:

> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> "git submodule foreach $cmd $args" used to treat "$cmd $args" the same
>   way "ssh" did, concatenating them into a single string and letting the
>   shell unquote. Careless users who forget to sufficiently quote $args
>   get their argument split at $IFS whitespaces by the shell, and got
>   unexpected results due to this. Starting from this release, the
>   command line is passed directly to the shell, if it has an argument.
>
> Read-only support for experimental loose-object format, in which users
>   could optionally choose to write their loose objects for a short
>   while between v1.4.3 and v1.5.3 era, has been dropped.
>
> The meanings of the "--tags" option to "git fetch" has changed; the
>   command fetches tags *in addition to* what is fetched by the same
>   command line without the option.
>
> The way "git push $there $what" interprets the $what part given on the
>   command line, when it does not have a colon that explicitly tells us
>   what ref at the $there repository is to be updated, has been enhanced.
>
> A handful of ancient commands that have long been deprecated are
>   finally gone (repo-config, tar-tree, lost-found, and peek-remote).